# Does anyone have example code using encodeBytes:length:forKey:?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need it for my NSCoder classes apparently and it would be useful if I can see a real example of this and its corresponding method.

The reason I feel I need it is when my method tries to encodeObject for an NSString*, it complains saying:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -encodeBytes:length:forKey: only defined for abstract class.  Define -[JSONEncoder encodeBytes:length:forKey:]!'

Thanks.

The method in JSONEncoder: (https://github.com/ontometrics/JSONCoding) I couldn't get the static library thing to work, so I'm trying to work directly with the code.

```
- (void)encodeObject:(id)object {
    [self push:object];
    [object encodeWithCoder:self];

    finalJSONObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[self topObject] forKey:[[[object class] description] camelcaseString]];

    [self pop];
}
```

Comment: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-08-12-implementing-nscoding.html

Comment: that blog mentions the method, but does not give example code for it.

Comment: @AaronBratcher: Perhaps you should show the definition of your class and what you have tried so far. It is easier to help with a concrete problem.

Comment: NSString is NSCoder compliant... So something else is up.

Comment: We need to see your code, because that error message sounds like you're sending `encodeObject:` to a JSONEncoder instance.

Comment: initial question updated with the method source. The object being passed is an NSString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the `JSONEncoder` is mainly meant to encode objects from custom classes (which must implement the `NSCoding` protocol). For example, if you define a class `Person` with a string property:

```
@interface Person : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end

@implementation Person
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
}
@end
```

then you can encode an object of this class without problems using `JSONEncoder`:

```
JSONEncoder *encoder = [JSONEncoder encoder];
Person *obj = [[Person alloc] init];
obj.name = @"John";
[encoder encodeObject:obj];
NSString *json = [encoder json];
NSLog(@"%@", json);
// Output: {"person":{"name":"John"}}
```

It works also with some "plain" Foundation types, e.g. with `NSNumber`, but the output is not very "nice", and I am not sure if `JSONEncoder` is meant to be used like that:

```
JSONEncoder *encoder = [JSONEncoder encoder];
NSNumber *obj = @1234;
[encoder encodeObject:obj];
NSString *json = [encoder json];
NSLog(@"%@", json);
// Output: {"__NSCFNumber":{"NS.intval":1234}}
```

In this case, the `encodeInt64:forKey:` method of `JSONEncoder` is called internally.

However, as you noticed, it does not work with `NSString`:

```
JSONEncoder *encoder = [JSONEncoder encoder];
NSString *obj = @"Hello world";
[encoder encodeObject:obj];
// Exception: *** -encodeBytes:length:forKey: only defined for abstract class.  Define -[JSONEncoder encodeBytes:length:forKey:]!
```

The reason for the exception is that `NSString` is `NSCoding` compliant, but it uses the `-encodeBytes:length:forKey:` of the coder, and `JSONEncoder` *does not implement this method*.

Implementing that method is not too difficult, this is a quick-and-dirty attempt:

```
- (void)encodeBytes:(const uint8_t *)bytesp length:(NSUInteger)lenv forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytesp length:lenv encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self setObject:s forKey:key];
}
```

If you add this code to "JSONEncoder.m", then you can encode a plain `NSString` without getting an exception, the result looks like this:

```
{"__NSCFConstantString":{"NS.bytes":"Hello world"}}
```

But again, I am not sure if `JSONEncoder` is meant to be used like this.

Comment: Well Im willing to try it. I don't suppose you have the reverse to get the string back?

Comment: @AaronBratcher: I have thought about this once again. According to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt, *"A JSON text is a serialized object or array"* and an object is a collection name/value pairs. In other words, the top-level JSON object is always a dictionary or array. Therefore encoding a single string as JSON does not make much sense. I think that you should wrap your string into a custom class and encode that. - Btw. Why do you need JSONEncoder at all? NSDictionary and NSArray can be encoded with the built-in NSJSONSerialization class.

Comment: The string should be encoded as an object this way: variableName:value. Much like the other types that are encoded using JSONEncoder. I would like to receive and send JSON to my server and to parse it directly into/out of my custom classes.

Comment: @AaronBratcher: But a custom class with a string property seems to work (see the `Person` example in my answer). Probably I haven't understood your problem yet. Perhaps you can show the definition of your custom class.

Comment: Looking at all of this, I think I'll just add a specific encodeString method. I was hoping to learn about encodeBytes in the process.

Comment: @AaronBratcher: I still don't understand why you need that. Encoding a custom class with a string property just works. But if you don't show your actual code I cannot help further. - And I gave you an example of a `encodeBytes` method hoping that it might help.

Comment: The ability to have an array of another class with that class having arrays of other classes all being JSON serialized/parsed by a single call is a benefit. I did see your example and I really appreciate it. It helps me learn more. I also realized that I should have been using encodeObject:forKey: to do my string encodings. Not sure how I missed that. I really do appreciate all your help! Thanks. :)

Comment: @AaronBratcher: I am glad that your problem is solved. If my answer helped it would be nice if you "accept" it by clicking on the check mark.